# Laravel: Filter logs based on the logs from specific logging channels

Tags: php, laravel, logging, slack, monolog

I have a logging infra in laravel that sends all of the error logs to a Slack channel.
Here's the config - [image: Slack log config]

We have some logs, coming from the front end, that we want to filter from reaching the slack channel.
I tried to add a 'tap' config, I get the logs and can customize it, but I'm unable to block it from being sent to Slack.

Has anyone ever had this problem and can shed some light? Maybe there's a better way of doing it? I really don't want to add it in the FrontEnd as I would like to have all of the errors that are happening in Sentry, but I don't want it alerting us on Slack

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I kind of have the same problem, I want to intercept the logs before sending to slack channel and filter out specific logs.

Comment: I went up the call hierarchy and filtered there, before it is sent to the actual log

Comment: I am also having this same issue. I would like to stop Slack logger for specific exception types, but still log to file. I have been unable to find where to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by checking exception type in my ExceptionHandler. In addition logging level has been set to error for Slack logging. So changing the log level to debug will skip logging to Slack.

config/logging.php

```
'slack' => [
    'driver' => 'slack',
    'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
    'level' => 'error',
],
```

app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function report(Throwable $e)
{
    if ($this->shouldntReport($e)) {
        return;
    }

    if (method_exists($e, 'report')) {
        if ($e->report() !== false) {
            return;
        }
    }

    try {
        $logger = app(LoggerInterface::class);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw $e; // throw the original exception
    }

    // Check exception type and log with different level, if needed.
    if(get_class($e) === ExceptionNotToLogToSlack::class) {
        $logger->debug($e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);
    } else {
        $logger->error($e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);
    }
}
```